# How to install CocosSharp in Xamarin.Forms Protable project?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, cocossharp

I created a Blank App (Xamarin.Forms Portable). I set up and run HAXM, Android and iOS projects works great. I wanted to add a CocosSharp view, so I tried to install CocosSharp nuget package. But I'm getting this errors:

[image]

Is this another bug? How can I fix it? I just wanted to add a CocosSharp to default, blank Xamarin.Forms.

Thanks

EDIT:
When I try to uncheck "Windows Phone Silverlight " I have an error:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default (template created) Xamarin.Forms PCL-based project targets `Profile259` and that includes `SilverLight` support which is not supported by `CocosSharp`.

Change your PCL-based project to `Profile111` which removes `Silverlight` support and you will be able to add the `CocosSharp` package.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I change the profile of the project? Is it for every project (iOS and Android too) or just PCL ?

Comment: @IshThomas Just the PCL-based one(s), not the native projects. Open the project properties and change it there: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg597391(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_3

Comment: I can't see anything saying "Profile" "259" or "111" neither in the project properties nor in the link. But I can see "Targets", 'Silverlight 5' is unchecked. 'Windows Phone Silverlight 8' is checked, but I can't uncheck it.. "The project's targets cannot be changed." error appears